# Thumbnail and price not showing on related products section

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

Well, I'm trying to create a module with the related products I have in my shop. My template has a file in the route /theme-name/woocommerce/single-product/related.php. In this we can see some code of how it call to the related product. It use the template as the listing product page (same template), but when I tried to shpw the thumbnail or the price it doesn't work. It only show me the title of the product, nothing else.

This is the code I have in my template for the file /related.php

```php
<?php 
if ( $related_products ) : ?>
    <section id="nm-related" class="related products">
        <div class="nm-row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Related products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
                <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>
                    <?php foreach ( $related_products as $related_product ) : ?>
                        <?php
                            $post_object = get_post( $related_product->get_id() );
                            setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );
                            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
<?php endif;
```

After that I use the "content-product" template like the listing page, where I don't have any problem.

For example, to show the product thumbnail I tried this:

```php
<div class="nm-shop-loop-thumbnail nm-loader">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" class="nm-shop-loop-thumbnail-link woocommerce-LoopProduct-link">
        <?php
        $id_pro = get_the_ID();
        $pro_2 = get_post_thumbnail_id($id_pro);
        $featured_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $pro_2 );
        if(! empty( $featured_image_url )) { ?>
            <?php
            /**
            * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title.
            *
            * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
            * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
            */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
        } else { ?>
            <img src="https://cdn.mtods.ch/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/20190409092145/nopic.jpg" data-src="https://cdn.mtods.ch/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/20190409092145/nopic.jpg" data-srcset="https://cdn.mtods.ch/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/20190409092145/nopic.jpg 350w, https://cdn.mtods.ch/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/20190409092145/nopic.jpg 250w, https://cdn.mtods.ch/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/20190409092145/nopic.jpg 400w" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 350px) 100vw, 350px" width="350" height="420" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail wp-post-image  lazyloaded" srcset="https://cdn.mtods.ch/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/20190409092145/nopic.jpg 350w, https://cdn.mtods.ch/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/20190409092145/nopic.jpg 250w, https://cdn.mtods.ch/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/20190409092145/nopic.jpg 400w">
          <?php
          }
          ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

And as I said, it works for the listing page but not inside single page product in related products section.

The $id_pro variable work in both pages, it shows the id of the product, but when I try to get the thumbnail URL with this id it return me "".

In the first image you can see the example for the listing page, on the other hand, in the second image you can see the example for the related products for the single product page:

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you let me know your site link ? so that I can check it ?

Comment: @Alice yep, here is the link of the listing page (http://developmentmto.wpengine.com/en-de/shop/) and for the single page product (http://developmentmto.wpengine.com/en-de/product/1911/)

Comment: can you replace  do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' ) with echo '<img src="'.$featured_image_url.'">'; and me know ?

Comment: the thing is woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title using thumbnail image for current (details page) product page

Comment: @Alice I tried but nothing happened. The thing is that the if question (! empty( $featured_image_url )) always return empty on single product page (for related) but not for listing page (it shows the image)

Comment: can you print $id_pro and $pro_2 both to see where it is getting messed ?

Comment: @Alice oki is done, as u can see on the listing page are the 3 variables defined with their values but on single product page not

Comment: @Alice any news?

Answer (score 0):

I change the functionality and I created a new related product module, but still not working I don't know why...

I tried this:

- In my related.php:

  // Same category products query
              $mproduct = new WP_Query(array(
                  'post_type' => 'product',
                  'product_cat' => $cat_slug,
                  'posts_per_page' => -1,
              ));

  ```
          // Get query data
          $posts = $mproduct->get_posts();
          $num = $mproduct->post_count;


          // Create new array with the actual product in it
          $array_pro = [];
          $array_pro[] = $product_id;

          // Function for check if product is in array
          function test_function($rand_pro, $array_pro, $posts, $num) {
              if (in_array($rand_pro, $array_pro)) {
                  $new_pro_id = $posts[rand(0,$num-1)]->ID;
                  return true;
              } else {
                  return false;
              }
          }

          // If array is not full insert next elements
          while (count($array_pro) < 5) {
              $rand_pro = $posts[rand(0,$num-1)]->ID;
              $pro_in_array = test_function($rand_pro, $array_pro, $posts, $num);
              if ($pro_in_array == false) {
                  $array_pro[] = $rand_pro;
              }
          }

          // Remove first element of array
          array_shift($array_pro);

          ?>
          <div class="related-products-row">
              <?php
              foreach( $array_pro as $post ) { 
                  $rel_product_id = $post;
                  $rel_product_title = get_the_title($rel_product_id);
                  $rel_product_link = get_the_permalink($rel_product_id);
                  $rel_product_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail($rel_product_id);
                  $_product = wc_get_product( $rel_product_id );
                  $rel_product_ref = $_product->get_attribute( 'reference' );
                  ?>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                      <p><?php echo $rel_product_img_url; ?></p>
                  </div>
                  <?php
              }
          ?>
          </div>
  ```

If you can see, when I try to getthe name I don't have problems but when I try to get the post_thumbnail_url or ref_number it doesn't show anything I don't know why.